# Best way to rollback all changes to an Ember Data model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember-data to edit a user with automatic model resolution

```
this.route('user', function() {
  this.route('edit', { path: ':user_id'})
});
```

This works fine and the user can modify all aspects of the model `DS.attribute`, `DS.belongsTo` and `DS.hasMany`.

The user can navigate away in a number of ways, in which case all changes should be removed from the model.

- Clicking a  `Cancel` button
- Clicking the `Broswer Back` button
- Clicking the `Save` button, the remote request `fails`, then navigating away from the page.
- Just Clicking some other link on the page which takes them somewhere else.

The changes should only be applied if the user explicitly wants them to by clicking the `Save` button and the server request is successful.

I considered using [ember-buffered-proxy](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-buffered-proxy) but I am not sure how this will cope with DS.belongsTo and DS.hasMany relationships.  Regardless, before saving the model I will need to do  `buffer.applyBufferedChanges();` before saving and if the server fails I am in the save situation as before.

The `willTransition` hook in the route seems like the obvious place to do this but how can I ensure all changes are removed from the model given `rollbackAttributes()` only works for `DS.attribute` controls.

Comment: If you use the "Actions up, data down" principle [(1)](http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/data-down-actions-up/) [(2)](https://dockyard.com/blog/2015/10/14/best-practices-data-down-actions-up) and use one-way bindings in the template so that changes when editing are not immediately propagated to the model but when you click "save" then the model can be updated via an appropriate action (so that the model owns the code to update itself rather than having it scattered in lots of routes/components) and if you move away from the edit page then the changes are just discarded.

Comment: Can't really see how this solves the problem because the ember-data model is the model being returned from the routes model hook.

Comment: And returning an empty object and later saving it as a model, is that something you'll consider ?

Comment: @TameBadger returning an empty object from where?  The promise?

Comment: The route model hook

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing the Ember.Route [`refresh()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh) method inside the route's [`willTransition()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_willTransition) action hook, like this:

```
action: {
  willTransition() {
    const unsavedModel = this.get('unsaved');
    if (unsavedModel) {
      this.refresh();
    }
  }
}
```

The [`refresh()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh) method can be used for "re-querying the server for the latest information using the same parameters as when the route was first entered."

I've suggested a flag named `unsaved`, which can default to `true`, unless it has been set to `false` at some point during a successful `save`, prior to transitioning.